Redshift Managed VPC Endpoint
I am trying to create Redshift-managed VPC Endpoint, but on the screen I can simply not select my cluster id, infact, the list is empty.

I wanted to use Redshift Managed VPC Endpoint from within my Account, I do not have any other VPC to grant access to, infact, what I wanted, was that I could create Redshift Managed Endpoint in my 10. routable Subnet, whereas my complete Redshift cluster could stay in non-routable 100. subnets.
Can any one help? I tried creating an IAM role with relevant ec2 endpoint permissions, infact for testing purposes full access, but that also does not help. The trust policy however looks like this, posting here if this could be incorrect.


What do you mean by "non-routable 100. subnets"? Are you saying that you have allocated 100.x.x.x IP addresses to your VPC? That's probably not a good idea, since that is a public IP address owned by somebody on the Internet. You should really stick to using Private network - Wikipedia ranges. Not sure if that is causing your problem.

Hi, thank you for reply, I am working in a company where we have 2 CIDR blocks available for each of our VPC. one of them is a big 100. block. and these are non-routable private ips. Whereas the other CIDR block is a valid 10. block. This leads to 10. subnets, which are well connected with on-premise infra, and 100. subnnets, which are kinda superficial, and only available within VPC. My attempt is to create a Redshift managed vpc end point that I can place in valid 10. subnet, and keep the actual cluster in such 100. subnet. However, I hit this problem, that I can never select cluster id.

If you put the Redshift cluster in the 10. subnet, can you create the Redshift Managed VPC Endpoint?

Please check if the Redshift cluster has "Cluster Relocation" enabled.  it requires cluster relocation enabled for Redshift cluster so that it appears in the drop down while creating the Redshift managed VPC end point

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
